# "Миллиона" или "миллионов"?

Tags: числительные, управление

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно: "заработал более 3,6 миллиона" или "более 3,6 миллионов"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Правильно: Заработал более 3,6 миллиона.

При смешанном числе существительным управляет дробь, а не целое число.

**Розенталь §166, п. 8**